# Help with Strong Induction proof

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

$$A_n = \begin{cases}
3,&n=1\\
9,&n=2\\
2A_{n-1},&n\neq1\text{ and }n\text{ odd}\\
4A_{n-1},&n\text{ even}
\end{cases}$$

Need to prove $A_n \leq 3^n$  $∀n$ ∈ $N≥1$ by strong induction. After case $n = 1$ and $n = 2$, i thought about going for something like $n = 2k$ for $n$ even and $n = 2k + 1$ for $n$ odd but i got stuck and have yet no idea how to proceed after the two inicial cases.

See the image for better visualization
[In the image, "se" equals to "if, "par" = even, "impar" = odd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whOY0.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax commands aren't effective unless they're enclosed in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.

Comment: Please add more information about your attempt to solve the problem, or the question will likely be closed.  What induction hypothesis did you make?  What do you need to prove.  How did you attempt to prove it?  Exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry about that! Thank you, for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $n$ is even, then $n-1$ is odd. If $n$ is odd, then $n-1$ is even. In the first case, we get for even $n>2$ $$A_n=4A_{n-1}=4\cdot 2A_{n-2}=8A_{n-2}.$$ For the second case, we get the same result. Hence, we have $$A_n=8A_{n-2}\leq 8\cdot 3^{n-2}<3^2\cdot 3^{n-2}.$$